# Na if not (specific format)

Tags: r, format, string-formatting, data-cleaning

I would like the values that have something else that a 0 on the fourth number of a numeric variable to be NA's.

The following code is my try:

```
dataframecolumn[which(substring(dataframecolumn) != %%%0)] = NA
```

But I cannot get it to work. Can someone help me on this one?

Comment: if you want to use `substring()`, you can try `substring(12353, 4, 4) != "0"`

Comment: That's not the correct syntax for `substring`. Try `?substring` to see what you need.

Comment: For some reason I had a hard time finding this.. Thanks! (it works beautifully)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like i wrote in the comment, for `substring()` you could use:

```
dataframecolumn[substring(dataframecolumn, 4, 4) != "0"] <- NA
```